# error: no match for ' operator >>' ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Qué debo hacer?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Estoy aprendiendo a programar por codeblocks, pero la verdad esto hace semanas que vengo tratando de solucionarlo y no puedo.

Aquí se encuentra el código

```
int main()
{
  int n1;
  int n2;
  int n3;
  int max1;

  cout <<"Ingrese primer numero" <<;
  cin >> n1 >> endl;
  cout << "Ingrese segundo numero" <<;
  cin >> n2 >> endl;
  cout << Ingrese tercer numero" <<;
  cin >> n3 >> endl;

}
```

Y aquí está la imagen del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el `#include <iostream>`

Comment: Saludos @Juani, por favor podrías colocar el código, una imagen no facilita mucho a los demás para que te ayuden.

Comment: No pienso hacer click en la imágen para ver el código... ¿por qué no copia-pegas el código?

Comment: Creo que tu problema es que estas terminando la sentencia con "<<;" y siempre despues de "<<" debe ir una expresion que utilices para el cout. Prueba con: count << "Ingrese primer numero: "; solamente

Comment: @EmilianoTorres la línea en que ha dibujado la flecha roja con el error ni siquiera es la que el IDE dice que es errónea (línea 13 vs línea 15).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, es verdad, pero si te fijas en los messages, la primer linea que le marca error es la 13 (que él no la subraya). Ahi está el error. Tiene que terminar la sentencia como se lo indico en el comentario anterior.

Comment: @EmilianoTorres Estoy sinceramente pensando que esta pregunta [es una broma](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers), entre poner el código en una imágen y tener un error que se comprende tan sólo leyendo los mensajes de error.

Answer (score 4):

En realidad tienes dos errores, tanto con los `cout` como con los `cin`, primero no debes de dejar `<<` y no poner ningún parámetro, debes de agregar algo y después en el con los `>>` del `cin` no puedes poner el `endl`

Así es como lo tienes tu:

```
cout << "Ingrese primer numero" <<; //aquí esta el primer error
cin >> n1 >> endl; //aquí está el segundo error
```

Sí vas a agregar un `endl` solo puede ser en un `cout`

Forma correcta

```
cout << "Ingrese primer numero" << endl;
cin >> n1;
cout << endl;  //también puedes usar cout<< "\n";
```

Y debes hacer lo mismo con el resto del código

Comment: Ah buenisimo! perdón los comments arriba, no sabía poner bien la imagen!

Ahora pruebo con eso Randall! muchas gracias! y los demas por comentar! Saludos!

Comment: en el `cin >> n1` te falto el `;`